# Pagina carga después de que hacer clic en buton

Tags: javascript

¿Alguien sabe porque me vuelve a cargar la pagina despues de que hago clic en un boton?

Mi codigo en un script y mando llamar una funcion y esa funcion a otra

```
$("#siguiente").click(function(e){console.log("sig");
validartipodeenvio();
alert("Espera"); alert("Actividad: "+actividad+"\n"+"Area que estudia: "+area_que_estudia+"\n"+"Tiempo transcurrrido"+tiempo_transcurrrido+"\n"+"Medio_obtencion:"+medio_obtencion+"\n"+"requisitos_contratacion:"+requisitos_contratacion+"\n"+"idioma_uso_trabajo:"+idioma_uso_trabajo+"\n"+"Antiguedad de empleo:"+antiguedad_empleo+"\n"+"año de ingreso:"+anio_ingreso+"\n"+"SAlario Min:"+salario_min+"\n"+"Nivel Jerarquico"+"\n"+"condicion_trabajo"+condicion_trabajo+ "/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n");});
```

Comment: se necesitaria ver tambien tu otro método

Comment: no ya elimine el metodo y me hace lo mismo

Comment: También limipiaste la cache de tu navegador? porque los js tienden a quedarse cachados, revistaste la consola? marca algo?

Comment: nou dejame intentar eso...

Answer (score 1):

Si tu botón en tu `HTML` esta como tipo `submit` su comportamiento natural es enviar la información. Sin embargo, para hacerla llegar a su destino, debe de recargar el navegador, prueba con `preventDefault()`.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera...

```js
$("#siguiente").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("sig");
validartipodeenvio();
alert("Espera"); alert("Actividad: "+actividad+"\n"+"Area que estudia: "+area_que_estudia+"\n"+"Tiempo transcurrrido"+tiempo_transcurrrido+"\n"+"Medio_obtencion:"+medio_obtencion+"\n"+"requisitos_contratacion:"+requisitos_contratacion+"\n"+"idioma_uso_trabajo:"+idioma_uso_trabajo+"\n"+"Antiguedad de empleo:"+antiguedad_empleo+"\n"+"año de ingreso:"+anio_ingreso+"\n"+"SAlario Min:"+salario_min+"\n"+"Nivel Jerarquico"+"\n"+"condicion_trabajo"+condicion_trabajo+ "/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n"+"/n");});
```

En otras palabras, la acción por defecto de un submit, siempre recargará el navegador y hará que pierdas el DOM actual.

Para prevenir esto, .preventDefault() de jQuery, cancela el comportamiento y/o defecto natural de un elemento.

Si el problema persiste presiona en tu navegador, dentro de la página de tu proyecto Control + F5 para limpiarlo.